# Datagrid.Resources сбивает стиль MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, mahapps-metro

Есть некоторый datagrid по первой колонке которого я привязываю context menu. Но при применении библиотеки mahApps.Metro, к datagrid применяется стиль не полностью, ячейка к которой привязывал context menu остается старой.

xaml datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="studentsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="4" Margin="5,5,5,5"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              IsReadOnly="True">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="studentsContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Переглянути повну інформацію про студента"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Переглянути прогули студента"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ІД " Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="70" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource studentsContextMenu}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Width="30" TextChanged="txtId_TextChanged" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ПІБ " Binding="{Binding Path=Full_name}" Width="10*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Width="100" TextChanged="txtName_TextChanged" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер телефону " Binding="{Binding Path=phone_number}" Width="15*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" Width="100" TextChanged="txtPhone_TextChanged" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

грубо говоря ресурсы датагрида которые я применяю к столбцу сбрасывают его стиль на стандартный. Я так понял, что нужно прописать этот стиль еще раз в DataGrid.Resources, но незнаю как это сделать. Может кто показать как исправить?

Comment: Пришла мысля, использовать BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGrid}". Чтобы использовать стиль который базируется на другом стиле, но не знаю как правильно им пользоваться, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему тем, что прописал, что мой новый стиль будет базироваться на метро стиле, проблема была в том, что я пытался примерить стиль датагрида к ячейке, по этому мне нужно было найти название стиля для ячейки и нашел. Прописал BasedOn = "{StaticResource MetroDataGridCell}" и все отлично заработало.